# Is there a way to remove parameters during run-time?

Tags: anylogic

I am creating a population of agents using around 40 mapped parameters. These parameters are just used in the initialisation of the population. However, the problem is that when creating a new agent these many parameters will be required in the arguments without an actual need for them. Just to give you an idea how ugly it looks like.

```
add_households(int, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, boolean)
```

Therefore, I was wondering if there is a way to remove/hide these parameters after no longer needed. It would be great to be looking like this :

```
add_households(int, boolean)
```

If not possible, the other solutions that I will be looking for are:

- Maybe there is something similar to parameters mapping for variables. (as variables will not show as arguments.
- Moving the whole population after being initialised to a new Agent class with the wanted parameters only. (The main thing here is to keep the created connections with other agent classes)

I appreciate any other suggestions for this problem. 
Thank you in advance;

### A Possible Solution

Amy's suggestion is elegant in my opinion. However, it did not work exactly as suggested. When typing: `objHousehold.initRuntimeParamters( set_age(5), set_p_HH_willing_to_change(true));`
It throws an error stating:

```
The method set_age(int) is undefined for the type Main.
The method set_p_HH_willing_to_change(boolen) is undefined for the type Main.
```

However, with a littel change I managed to access the wanted parameters only by typing:

```
Household objHousehold = add_households();
households(objHousehold.getIndex()).set_age(5);
households(objHousehold.getIndex()).set_p_HH_willing_to_change(true);
```

Comment: I've never worked with anylogic specifically, but most languages should have a way to set default values for the parameters, which should allow you to not use all of them at runtime.

Comment: > However, it did not work exactly as suggested

You misinterpreted Amy's answer. She meant that your `set_` calls are *in your `initRuntimeParameters` function* (defined within your `Household` agent).

Comment: Thank you Stuart. I didn't get that at from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always do add_households(), which would take the default parameters.  You could then call a function to set only the 2 you are interested in.

```
Household objHousehold = add_households();
objHousehold.initRuntimeParamters( int, boolean );
```

within initRuntimeParameters, use set_parameterName( value ) to set the parameter value.

Comment: Hi Amy, Thank you for your continuous help. This code for some reason throws the error: 'The method set_age(int) is undefined for the type Main.'  But, I managed to get it  working by this code Household objHousehold = add_households();
households(objHousehold.getIndex()).set_age(5);
households(objHousehold.getIndex()).set_p_HH_willing_to_change(true);

Comment: Yes, I should have clarified.  The syntax is object.set_parameter( value ).